# Difference transformation and Stationarization of Moving Average

Tags: time-series, stationarity, moving-average, acf-pacf, differencing

I have a temperature sensor data, I want to denoise it. The first thing that came to my mind was to take the moving average, it was very smooth but it is still not stationary. If I take the log difference, it is stationary according to ADF and KPSS, but is this the right thing to do? Is it right to the difference transform of the moving average? I am very confused about this. Can you evaluate it in terms of time series context? Also, my second question is whether the ACF/PACF graphs of a moving average filtered data make any sense? Let me ask the same thing for the log difference of ma.